# How can i make an arrow with inner text in html, css, react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image: An arrow]

I tried to do this with position: relative, but i want adaptive site, so it doesnt fit me. After i tried to make svg image, but it cant contain text. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that there would be a hundred more ways. This is one of them:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid green;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>4.7</div>
```